# BIOS doesn't work if HDD is inserted

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I have samsung NP-RC510 laptop.The screen hangs at the starting samsung logo if the HDD is connected. While pressing the key it hangs not even loading into the BIOS menu. If the HDD is removed the BIOS menu works normally. What would be the problem? Is there any solution? If the HDD is connected as portable drive , the windows/Linux(tried in both) not recognizing.

Comment: Sounds like the HDD need to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mostly sounds like the harddisk is broken. The system recognized it, but it can't identify itself, as the heads can't read the alignement of the platter, or another problem.

It might also be incompatible with the chipset, or the s-ata wire is broken, but most likely it's just a dead harddisk.

You might want to wait for some minutes, so the hdd might recognize and timeout.